# Resharper shows "Method is never used" to the "Main" method

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64 bit) Version 17.3.0 and JetBrains ReSharper 2022.2 Build 222.0.20220728.74125.

Resharper shows "Method Main is never used" but I want to suppress this only if the target is entry point method.
I know I can suppress this by insert the comment to the code but it bothers me and code is polluted.
Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to update R#. I'm using `JetBrains ReSharper 2022.2.1 Build 222.0.20220808.100806 built on 2022-08-08` and it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, `UnusedMethod` and `args` are considered unsed by R#, but not `Main`.

Maybe you can share a sample repo if resetting all R# caches and deleting all `bin` and `obj` folders don't help.

Comment: Thank you! I reset the cache and it helps me!!